# Stucco repair, no membrane?

Tags: roof, outdoor, plaster, stucco

I was doing a crack repair on my grandparents' house. The crack was in stucco located in an outside soffit on the 1st floor.

I removed the stucco and to my surprise there was no membrane, just what appeared to be gypsum or drywall over some form of paper that resembled the back of drywall boards (the 2nd floor soffits use cement board). I was expecting to see: stucco, mesh, black membrane material. Whats strange though is that I've seen black membrane behind mesh on the vertical walls. That's why I felt in these areas they might have cut corners. The area in question doesn't see much direct water, but still.

I repaired the crack already, but I was rather concerned that it would have been done this way

Is this common practice? My grandparents live in a development where all the houses are very similar so I suspect this was used in every house here. The house was built in the late 1990s.

Comment: Please use the [edit] underneath your post if you want to include extra information asked for in comments. Thanks!